# Youtube DataAPI's publishedAt property giving the date the video was uploaded, not gone public

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I've been working with Youtube API for the last couple days and now I stumbled upon a problem which I cannot solve.

I'm 'leeching' videos off channels and inserting some data into my SQL database, The problem is `PlaylistItems`' property `publishedAt`.

It gives me the date of when the video was uploaded - as you know some channels keep their videos private upon release date - I want just the release date, as it shows ordinary users.

Any way to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I turned up using Youtube API v2, Because using Youtube API v3 for this was a fresh hell.

Usage:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ID/uploads
or if you want it in JSON:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ID/uploads?alt=jsonc&v=2

Docs:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos

:)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the publishedAt attribute you're discussing does not represent upload time but instead represents when a video was added to the playlist -- which, of course, makes sense, given that you're looking at the playlistItem object.

If instead you mean you're looking at the video->list object, then yes ... the publishedAt attribute represents the upload date.

As far as I know, there is no way to get the date that a video was made public.

Comment: Oh, well the funny thing is that it gives me the day it was made public if I request a snippet part from the videos API on that youtube channel. It's just very problematic beacuse I need to get last uploads from that user, and the only way I have found to do it is through the uploads playlist - which now I see feeds me wrong information =/ Do you have any idea for me? Thanks!

Comment: If the videos.list endpoint is giving you the date you want, then all you'd need to do is take the videos from the uploads playlist and do a videos.list call with them. You can batch process them; i.e. get all the playlist items, gather their videoIDs into a comma-separated list, and pass that to the videos.list service and get back all the snippets for them with a single call.

Comment: Yes, but if I'm getting uploads from 3 channels, 10 videos each -> x30 GET requests, isn't that cool :) eventually I turned up using the Youtube API v2 which has this option built-in and gives me what I need :)

Comment: No question that in some things v2 still has a few advantages (captions is another area), but they are actively working to deprecate v2, so it unfortunately isn't a long-term solution. Hopefully v3 will have what you need at that point! Best of luck.