# YouTube API property - latest video publish date that takes into account if changed from private to public

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I feel my question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828529/youtube-dataapis-publishedat-property-giving-the-date-the-video-was-uploaded-n) question, but the links provided in the accepted answer is throwing a 404 error, also we're using version 3.

We're using the publishedAt property within the YouTube API, and upon reading the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems), it basically says the below about publishedAt:

> The date and time that the item was added to the playlist.

But what if a video (that we are the owners of) was first created as private, then we changed it to public at a later date? The publishedAt seems to show the original date it was uploaded and not the day it went public. Is there another value we can use to get this date?

Comment: It depends on the way you access the endpoint (using an API key or an access token) and whether you're the owner of that particular video or not. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65004531/8327971) and [one particular comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002092/youtube-playlist-item-api-publishedat-field-clarification/65004531#comment114964741_65004531) attached to a similar question.

Comment: @stvar we're using an access token, and we are the owners of the videos.